# Default copyable derived classes

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a silly class hierarchy.

```
class Base {
public:
    Base() = default;
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual void print() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived() {
        stuff.resize(1000);
    }
    void print() override {
        cout << "Whatever\n";
    }
private:
    std::vector<int> stuff;
};
```

And I want to use it like this:

```
void printIt(Base* b) {
    b->print();
}

int main() {

    Derived d1;
    Derived d2 = d1;

    printIt(&d1);
    printIt(&d2);
}
```

This compiles and works fine, but Clang warns me:

> warning: definition of implicit copy constructor for 'Base' is deprecated because it has a user-declared destructor

That seems fine and correct - if people copy `Base` bad things will happen so I'll delete the copy constructor.

```
class Base {
public:
    Base() = default;
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual void print() = 0;

    Base(const Base&) = delete;
    Base& operator=(const Base&) = delete;
};
```

However then I get this error:

```
main.cpp:38:17: error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'Derived'
        Derived d2 = d1;
                ^    ~~
main.cpp:18:21: note: copy constructor of 'Derived' is implicitly deleted because base class 'Base' has a deleted copy
      constructor
    class Derived : public Base {
                    ^
main.cpp:14:9: note: 'Base' has been explicitly marked deleted here
        Base(const Base&) = delete;
        ^
```

Ok... fair enough. What if I try to add it back in explicitly?

```
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived() {
        stuff.resize(1000);
    }
    void print() override {
        cout << "Whatever\n";
    }

    Derived(const Derived&) = default;

private:
    std::vector<int> stuff;
};
```

Then:

```
main.cpp:40:17: error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'Derived'
        Derived d2 = d1;
                ^    ~~
main.cpp:27:9: note: explicitly defaulted function was implicitly deleted here
        Derived(const Derived&) = default;
        ^
main.cpp:18:21: note: copy constructor of 'Derived' is implicitly deleted because base class 'Base' has a deleted copy
      constructor
    class Derived : public Base {
                    ^
main.cpp:14:9: note: 'Base' has been explicitly marked deleted here
        Base(const Base&) = delete;
        ^
```

No joy, which also kind of makes sense. What is the solution here? Should I just ignore the original warning? Maybe I should add `Base(Base&)` etc as `protected`?

Comment: I do not know a lot about this, but maybe removing the `virtual ~Base() = default;` is what you need. Your original warning tells you that the implicit copy constructor of `Base` is deprecated **because** it has a user declared destructor (note the emphasis in because).

Comment: The warning is due to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26687426). Best not to ignore it in new code.

Comment: @apalomer: Yes but I need the virtual destructor.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Why is it best to ignore it? The reason for adding it seems sensible at least.

Comment: @Timmmm - Your example doesn't seem to be inline with that requirement. You don't delete polymorphically. And I said it's best **not** to ignore the warning.

Comment: @StoryTeller Oh sorry I misread. And I don't delete it polymorphically in this example but I do in my code. Generally good idea to have all virtual classes support polymorphic deletion.

Comment: @Timmmm - I suppose so. The general advice of either a public virtual d'tor or a protected non-virtual one will result in the exact same warning either way.

Comment: Btw, what options did you give Clang? I'm playing with your example now and I'm not getting the warning.

Comment: It shows up with `-Weverything`.

Answer (score 1):

So it does compile without warnings if I make the copy/assignment `protected`. This seems like a reasonable solution:

```
class Base {
public:
    Base() = default;
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual void print() = 0;

protected:        
    Base(const Base&) = default;
    Base& operator=(const Base&) = default;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived() {
        stuff.resize(1000);
    }
    void print() override {
        cout << "Whatever\n";
    }

private:
    std::vector<int> stuff;
};

void printIt(Base* b) {
    b->print();
}

int main() {

    Derived d1;
    Derived d2 = d1;

    printIt(&d1);
    printIt(&d2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it like `Derived d2 = d1;` you will need to do 3 things:

1) make `Base` copy (and move) constructors and assignment operators `protected` and not `deleted` to delegate capability to allow/prohibit copy/move to derived class

```
protected: Base(const Base&) = default;
protected: Base& operator=(const Base&) = default;
```

2) make `Derived` copy (and move) constructors and assignment operators `public` to indicate that copy/move is allowed

```
public: Derived(const Derived&) = default;
public: Derived& operator=(Derived&) = default;
```

3) mark `Derived` as `final` to prevent accidental slicing when someone decides to derive from it again

```
class Derived final: public Base
```

Comment: It seems you don't actually need to declare `Derived`'s copy/assignment functions as public - I guess the implicitly generated ones are always public. And I guess by "splicing" you meant object slicing? Good point about final to prevent that.

Comment: Can you explain how does changing the constructors to protected is any different than in public? Both its children objects do know of the Base's constructor existence and 2 Base objects are created similarly in Public.

Comment: It means you can't do something like: `void foo(Base* a, Base* b) { *a = *b; }` ... I think.

Comment: @AlisherKassymov If constructor is `public` then anywhere in the program there could be some code performing `Base` to `Base` copy / move. Note that even though you define default `Base` constructor as `public` in reality is actually also `protected` because `Base` class is abstract. So you may want to change all the `Base` constructors to be `protected` for to make things more explicit.

Comment: @Timmmm There is indeed no need to do so, however it is always a good idea to make things explicit.

Comment: @VTT Ok, so if you make a parent class constructor protected, you can access it only if you create a Derived object am I right? So Protected is accessible only to its child class. Also, if you inherit the Base (Parent) in a protected way, there is no way to initiate a Base object of type Base, as only Derived has an access to it.